# Type of a variable in c

Tags: c, arrays

```
char s[10]="welcome";
```

Here for example `&s` is of type `char(*)[2]`.
Is there anyway in C to find the type of a variable like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "find the type"?  Have you tried http://cdecl.org?

Comment: If we try to print a variable with some other format specifier in c, it gives warning as the variable is of type "char *" but you are trying to print as "int" without cast. Likewise is there any proper way to find the variable type?

Comment: @Patashu: No, arrays are not "more or less pointers". I suggest you read section 6. of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: That particular declaration is invalid, because `s` isn't long enough to hold the string `"welcome"`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Interesting! Thank you :D

Comment: Incidentally the thing whose type is `char(*)[2]` is not a variable, it's an expression, `&s`. The only variable you've defined is `s`, and its type is `char[2]` (ignoring the invalid initializer). Both variables (more precisely *object*) and expressions have types.

Answer (score 1):

Most* compilers support the `typeof` operator, which can be quite handy. It is essentially equivalent to C++'s `decltype`, so you'd probably need a macro to turn it into something useful, like a string:

```
#define _STRINGIFY(arg) #arg
#define STRINGIFY(arg) _STRINGIFY(arg)
```

<sub>*: most compilers being clang, GCC, and I believe MSVC.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows but that information is discarded when the compilation is complete.  You cannot somehow ask at runtime for the textual description of what type of variable it is.  There is no method that will return the string "char(*)[2]"

To do this, you would have to either integrate with a C compiler or write a C compiler and run your code through it at runtime.

Comment: This is technically correct, barring extensions such as `typeof`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII your answer is better - I'll probably delete mine in a few minutes.